# Friction when a body is moving underneath another

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

I feel it would be better to explain my question through an example:

When I push a table (and it moves), with a mass atop of it, how does the mass stay on the table, as there is no direct horizontal force acting on the mass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a horizontal force acting on the mass, the static frictional force between the mass and the table. And that friction makes the mass atop of the table move.

If the static frictional force were not enough to keep the mass accelerating together with the table, the mass would start sliding on the table and we would then start using kinetic frictional force to calculate the acceleration of the mass.